# Getting information about type contained in boost::any

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any way by which I can extract the type information of `boost::any` type variable?

I tried to went through the source code of `any` class and found a [function giving some type information](https://github.com/boostorg/any/blob/develop/include/boost/any.hpp#L140), but couldn't find a way to call it in my program.

Comment: At run-time or at compile-time?

Comment: I need to know about it at runtime but if you have any way to know about type at compile time please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right there in the [examples for Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any/s02.html), no need to dig through the sources:

> The following predicates follow on from the previous definitions and demonstrate the use of queries on any objects:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> bool is_int(const boost::any & operand)
> {
>     return operand.type() == typeid(int);
> }
> ```

I.e., `any::type()` gives you the `typeid()` of the contained type.